# Reducing duplication in Maven submodule poms

Tags: maven

I am working on a project (not available to the public) in which I am using a multi-module Maven build system.  I have found that the submodule `pom.xml`s are almost identical, except that the `artifactId`, `finalName`, and `mainClass` are different.

Is there an easy way to remove the duplication?

Comment: What exactly is duplicated? Please show us those `pom`s.